# How to make an HTML table with merged cells

Tags: html, html-table

How to make this table like the 1st figure? I need to understand not just to make the code, please

[image]

I can't understand why the following code didn't work:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
         <table width="30%">
       <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>    
        <td rowspan="4">3</td>
        </tr>

       <tr> 
        <td> 4</td>
        <td rawspan="4">5 </td>
        <td>7 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td rowspan="6"> 6 <td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
         </tr>  

         <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td rawspan="3">10</td>
         </tr>  
    </table>
```

Comment: i want the code to display like the 1st figure , it doesn't I can't understand why

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the entire table the same, then you can use this:

CSS:

```css
  td {
  width: 33.3333%; 
  height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-wrap: none;
  }
  
  tr {
  height: 28px;
  }
  
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse; width: 48.3284%; height: 56px;"
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td >2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i have to make the table like the 1st figure in the picture

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question, he was struggling with `rowspan`s mainly.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a `table` you need to think in table `row`s. Try to slice up your table, you will see that there are six rows in total and three columns. So it's probably easier to start with a 6x3 table and add the necessary `rowspan`s later.

When you add `rowspan`, don't forget that that cell will expand down, so in the next row (or the one after if `rowspan="3"`) you need to remove that `td` cell.

Check out the snippet below:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td rowspan="3">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td rowspan="2">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```